# Как добится окончания всех запросов ajax в цикле?

Tags: jquery, ajax

```
function dm()
{
var result = '';
j.post('/x',function(r){
         j('table tr',r).each(function(){
          var url   = j(this).find('a').attr('href');
          j.get(url,function(e){
               result = result+j('#block',e).text();
        });             
         });
                     //alert(result);
         return result;
});
}
```

В результате я получаю пустой ответ, т.к. запросы все еще идут и цикл двигается.
Как же получить полный ответ? после того как запросы/цикл закончится

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 6):

Вам нужен [jQuery.Deferred](https://api.jquery.com/category/deferred-object/), который для таких вещей и создан, и в который оборачиваются все AJAX-вызовы. Этот объект позволяет довольно гибко работать с коллбеками успешного/неуспешного завершения; [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) позволяет сделать Deferred-объект из Deferred-объектов и запустить коллбэк тогда, когда они все выполнятся:

```
var calls = [];
$collection.each(function () {
    calls.push($.ajax({
        url: '',
        ...
    }));
});

$.when.apply($, calls).then(function () {
    // функция, которая будет выполнена после всех deferred-запросов.
});
```

(с [jQuery.when()](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.when/) немного сложная конструкция, которая вызвана неизвестным количеством запросов)

Также в jQuery на основе Deferred прекрасным образом строятся цепочки запросов

```
$.ajax({ ... }).done(function () { return $.ajax({ ... }); }).done(function () { return $.ajax({ ... }); });
```

Можно и так:

```
var callA = function () { return $.ajax({ ... }); };
var callB = function () { return $.ajax({ ... }); };
var callC = function () { return $.ajax({ ... }); };

callA().done(callB).done(callC);
```

Comment: Все-таки вот так - `callA.done(callB).done(callC);` делать нельзя. Запросы на сервер уйдут одновременно, а не по-цепочке. И предыдущий вариант страдает тем же недостатком...

Comment: Да, давно в этом копался. Там должны быть функции-обертки, возвращающие объект ajax.